# How do I convert an osx fileid to a filepath

Tags: macos, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4, pyobjc

I am using PyQt4, Python 2.7, Qt 4.8 on Mac OSX Yosmite.  I appear to have Drag-n-Drop working, can process drop event etc. If I drop a file in and print the path I get values like `/.file/id=6571367.11512812` Using this file-id I can't seem to open/process the file.
Here is the dropEvent() method.  Any ideas how to get the true file path?

```
def dropEvent(self, event):
    for url in event.mimeData().urls():
        path = url.path() # also tried url.toLocalFile().toLocal8Bit().data()
        print path
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            print "found"
        else:
           print "not found"
```

It seems to be related to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40449 which recommends upgrading to Qt5, which is will require a significant effort as I have vtk5, opencv, qgis and few others dependent on Qt4.

Anyone know of a workaround or a fix?

Comment: So your question is actually: how do I convert an osx `fileid` to a `filepath` using python? Presumably someone who knows [PyObjC](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/) should be able to answer that, so maybe you should reformulate your question with that in mind.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks.  Changed question and added another tag.

Comment: I recently answered this (I hadn't found this question before) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689562/pyqt-mimedata-filename/34731190#34731190

Comment: Awesome.  Above link to code works for me. Thanks.